# Javascript, store and retrieve first coordinates of an element on dragstart event

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, closures

I wonder how can I store and retrieve first the coordinates (offest) of an element on dragstart event.

I'm using interact.js but it's a general question...

So far I wrote this function, because I guess I have to use a closure and store the coordinates in a Javascript object:

```
 function checkStartPos(event) {
      var target = event.target,
      targetOffset = $(target).offset(),
      x = targetOffset.left,
      y =  targetOffset.top
        console.log('drag started!');

         return function() {

            return {
            x : x,
            y : y

      }

  }
```

On "dragend" event I would recall the original values to change the element style so my element get back to the original position...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make `x` and `y` into global variables? Note that you can also use the `event.clientX` and `clientY` properties rather than the jQuery `offset()` stuff.

```js
var x, y

$('#example').on('dragstart', function checkStartPos(event) {
    var target = event.target
    x = event.clientX
    y = event.clientY
    console.log('drag started at (' + x + ',' + y + ')')
}).on('dragend', function() {
    console.log('recall: (' + x + ',' + y + ')')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" style="width:100px;height:100px" draggable>stuff</div>
```

(I've not used `draggable` before, and the demo doesn't allow you to drag at the moment. However, getting things to drag didn't seem to be your problem, and the example JS should do what you wanted given the working setup you had before.)